# Script to check whether application is running; if not, start it

Tags: bash, macos, shell, variable-assignment, quotes

I run an application "OsiriX MD" on my Mac. Sometimes it inexplicably "quits." I want to run a script every hour to check whether it's running. If not, I want to re-start it. Would this work?

```
#!/bin/bash
PROCESS=OsiriX MD
number=$(ps aux | grep $PROCESS | wc -l)

if [ $number -gt 0 ]
then
    open $PROCESS;
fi
```

Comment: A `launchd` agent with `keepAlive` key might be the better choice.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use `pgrep` to check if a process is not (`!`) running:

```
process="OsiriX MD"
if ! pgrep -f "$process"; then
  echo "start application"
fi
```

---

See: `man pgrep`

Answer (score 2):

So far, I've had success with this code:

`#!/bin/bash
process="OsiriX\ MD"
if ! pgrep -f "$process"; then
  open -a /Applications/OsiriX\ MD.app/Contents/MacOS/OsiriX\ MD;
fi`

Does anyone see a potential problem with it?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Howard

Comment: This is probably not a problem, but why did you choose to open the app by directly invoking its executable file (.app/Contents/MacOS/...) instead of just `open -a appname.app`?

Answer (score 0):

The `watershed` util, (in *Debian*-based distros install it with `apt install watershed`), might be useful.

> Description: reduce superfluous executions of [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning) command
>      watershed may be run around a command such that any further attempts to
>      run the command while another copy is running will only result in one
>      initial further attempt.

To use it, the first instance, (and all further attempts), should be started with something like:

```
watershed "OsiriX MD" &
```

Or if the `OsiriX MD` needs the terminal itself:

```
watershed "OsiriX MD"
```

This saves a special lock file in `~/.watershed/` which `watershed` will later check for.  If `OsiriX MD` is still running `watershed` will wait until it's *not* running, then run it.  If `OsiriX MD` is not running, then `watershed` runs it.

One apparent bug: *third* instances seem to be ignored.  For example, suppose we run `watershed mc`, on terminal A, then on terminal B, then on terminal C.  We'll see `mc` on A, `watershed mc` on B & C both waiting.  Now close `mc` on A, and on B we'll see a new instance of `mc`, and on C `watershed mc` is still waiting.  Now close `mc` on B, and C shows the command prompt -- the third instance waited around uselessly.  On the other hand, if we had waited until we closed `mc` on A, *then* ran `watershed mc` on C, then closed mc on B, then `mc` would be on C.  *Two* instances work fine.